# ASP.NET Page Templates Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms

I know that in Windows Form Application you can inherit a Form and in ASP.NET u can inherit a page but some big constraint exist: ASPX page is not compiled in the library.

I tried to embed a User Control in DLL but Design Time is not supported, also I tried to make a Custom Server Control but in the end you are inheriting a control not Page.

So the question is what is the way to make your own library of Template Pages that u can inherit and use in different projects with design support .

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is kinda oldie, but maybe it will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163967.aspx

Comment: this example guide you to build a reusable template in the same website not between websites or projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Creating Reusable Page template](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/654877/Creating-Reusable-Page-template)

Here I've shown how to **Create a reusable page template**. To use your template in your another website or project you have to right click on the project **Add -> New Item**. **Add New Item** dialog box will appear. You can use the **Search Installed Templates** option and search your template or you can click on **Visual C#** tab on left panel of the dialog box and find your **Template**.

Note : Your **Template** might not appear if you click on **Visual C# -> Web** on **Add New Item** dialog box. Rather you have to search it in **Visual C#** tab.